# How to exit LS customs?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am new to GTA Online. I have stolen a car, brought it to LS Customs, modded it, and then...

I see no way to exit the customs! There is no suitable menu item. <kbd>Esc</kbd> has no effect (although it functions ok in all other situations). Also I don't know how exiting is supposed to be.

I am playing on the PC, Windows 7 64 bit, Steam, game fully updated, no cracks/mods/etc.

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: Press the escape button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're being asked to respray your car, thus meaning you're in LSC for the first time. You **have to** respray your car in order to pass the tutorial. In the future <kbd>Esc</kbd> should work.

If the game doesn't react to that, your game has glitched (it happens randomly sometimes) and you have to restart the game by pressing alt+f4 and confirming with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: It looks like that! There were non-skippable hints also. I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: I can approve this! I was confused by this as well. In general, if something (new) does not work as you expect it to. Look for a mission being displayed (like the one at the bottom in the screenshot) or check the *Brief* section in the pause menu.